# How to get data-attribute value of elements which is greater than given value using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes, custom-data-attribute

I have few textboxes and `data-attrribute` for installment number.

```
<input type="text" id="54" data-instno="12"/>
<input type="text" id="124" data-instno="13"/>
<input type="text" id="88" data-instno="14"/>
<input type="text" id="126" data-instno="15"/>
<input type="text" id="102" data-instno="16"/>
<input type="text" id="8" data-instno="17"/>
<input type="text" id="87" data-instno="18"/>
<input type="text" id="112" data-instno="19"/>
```

If my installment number is 15. i want to get controls have `data-instno>=15`. that means last 5 textboxes in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery [Has Attribute Selector [name]](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) to selecting target elements and use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filtering element has `data-instno` great than 15.

```
$("[data-instno]").filter(function(){
  return $(this).attr("data-instno") >= 15;
}).doSomething();
```

```js
$("[data-instno]").filter(function(){
  return $(this).attr("data-instno") >= 15;
}).css("background", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="54" data-instno="12"/>
<input type="text" id="124" data-instno="13"/>
<input type="text" id="88" data-instno="14"/>
<input type="text" id="126" data-instno="15"/>
<input type="text" id="102" data-instno="16"/>
<input type="text" id="8" data-instno="17"/>
<input type="text" id="87" data-instno="18"/>
<input type="text" id="112" data-instno="19"/>
```

If you want to get value of `data-instno` use this

```
var arr = $("[data-instno]").map(function(){
  return $(this).attr("data-instno");
}).get().filter(function(value){
  return value >= 15;
});
```

```js
var arr = $("[data-instno]").map(function(){
  return $(this).attr("data-instno");
}).get().filter(function(value){
  return value >= 15;
});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="54" data-instno="12"/>
<input type="text" id="124" data-instno="13"/>
<input type="text" id="88" data-instno="14"/>
<input type="text" id="126" data-instno="15"/>
<input type="text" id="102" data-instno="16"/>
<input type="text" id="8" data-instno="17"/>
<input type="text" id="87" data-instno="18"/>
<input type="text" id="112" data-instno="19"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just plain JavaScript:

```js
console.log( 
  [].filter.call(document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT'), 
    function(elem) {
      return elem.dataset.instno >= 15;
    })
);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="54" data-instno="12"/>
<input type="text" id="124" data-instno="13"/>
<input type="text" id="88" data-instno="14"/>
<input type="text" id="126" data-instno="15"/>
<input type="text" id="102" data-instno="16"/>
<input type="text" id="8" data-instno="17"/>
<input type="text" id="87" data-instno="18"/>
<input type="text" id="112" data-instno="19"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrNumber = new Array();
$('input[type=text]').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('data-instno') >= 15){
         arrNumber.push($(this).attr('data-instno'));
    }
});
```

use this you will get this as an array